# Simple Toggle with jQuery: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

What am I doing wrong with this Mootools toggle?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#trigger").click(function () {
            $("#trigger-banner").toggle();
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#trigger").click(function () {
                    $("#trigger-banner").toggle();
            });
    });
</script>
```

You forgot to close your ready document.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#trigger").click(function () {
        $("#trigger-banner").toggle();
    });
});
```